# Xcode 4.2.1 Storyboard many-to-one view return

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

My design has a 'key' view that is called from several different views.

Using Xcode Storyboard how can you 'push' the key view when the user needs it then 'pop' it off so that the user returns to the correct view?

It appears that the button can only be linked to one return point?

Thanks
Jim

Comment: You may have to do it programatically.  Manually setting segue transitions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, chown - you were correct.

The solution is to create a UIViewController subclass then use delegate protocol

DelegateClass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ReturnToMainMenu <NSObject>
@required
- (void) processSuccessful: (BOOL)success;
@end

@interface Recipe : UIViewController {
    id <ReturnToMainMenu> delegate;
}

@property (strong) id delegate;

-(IBAction)done:(id)sender;
@end
```

Delegateclass.m

```
-(IBAction)backToMainMenu:(id)sender {
    [[self delegate] processSuccessful:YES];
}
```

Then declare protocol in calling class

```
@interface FoodGroup : UIViewController <ReturnToMainMenu>

- (void) processSuccessful:(BOOL)success
{
    NSLog(@"Process completed");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    //[self performSelector:@selector(done:)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jim, your Recipe class should have a weak reference to its delegate to avoid the potential problem of retain cycles where the delegate and its owner hold references to each other, preventing proper deallocation of either.

Pre-ARC, delegates were typically (assign) properties. I don't believe ARC changes this in any way, other than changing assign to weak.